# I found a video on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KjHKwCZyAhQ and there is a part I don't understand. Can someone explain this part?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, youtube

```
FILE *f; 
int k = w*h; 
int s = 4 * k;
int filesize = 54 + s;

double factor = 39.375;
int m = static_cast<int>(factor);

int ppm = dpi*m;

unsigned char bmpfileheader[14] = {'B','M', 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 54,0,0,0};
unsigned char bmpinfoheader[40] = {40,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 1,0,24,0};
```

This is in the video at 3:43 to 6:55

I do not understand what the numbers are used for.

For example I don't understand why the factor is equal to 39.375 or why filesize is equal to 54 + s. ^

And I don't understand the use if unsigned char ... and what the numbers mean in the unsigned char.

I hope you can explain this to me.

Comment: Probably the first time I've seen a URL in the title. Do we need it? We generally don't want any reliance on off-site resources. Just ask the question about the code.

Comment: It's not an "unsigned char". It's an array of them. How much C++ do you know?

Comment: I realise it's not "cool" any more, but [read the documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the variable names, the `factor` is a conversion between PPM and DPI. Look it up on Wikipedia and you'll find it's 39.375.

The filesize is equal to 54+`s` because the output is BMP, which has a header and, as you can see from the array names, the total size of the header is 54. The bytes in the header have the values given in the `unsigned char` array, because that's how BMP works. Look it up on Wikipedia and you'll find out why.